# Generate IP address from MAC address in Python

Tags: python

I am looking for a way to generate IPv4 address of a device I own (in a local network) from its MAC address using a python script.

Is there any Ethernet API to do that? Or any other way?

Comment: Here is just googled solution for you!
[enter link description here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/90263/network-mac-address-conversion-to-ipv6-link-local-address/90264)

Comment: The only way that I can think of is to read the arp cache. Are you using Windows?

Comment: I am doing this on Raspberry Pi, so Raspbian OS, essentially Linux.

Comment: Is it your own device's MAC address you're trying to lookup the IP for, or a remote system's MAC address?

Comment: By the way the arp cache only stores ip addresses and mac addresses that have recently been sent arp requests. So most device will probably not be in the arp cache. Also, it is probably easier to just use `arp -n | grep **MAC ADDRESS** | awk '{print $1}'` and not use a python script at all

Comment: @Blckknght, yes MAC address of the microcontroller device that I own.

Comment: @DmitryYudin I am looking for IPv4 address

Comment: If its the local IP address for the interface corresponding to the MAC address you have, just run `ifconfig` (or some equivalent) and parse the output. It should have the MAC address labeled as something like "HWaddr". I'm afraid I can't be more exact, but I don't have a linux-based system to test on at the moment.